# Difference between unique and levels and the usage of suppresswarnings

Tags: r

I am right now doing the Intro to R programming course on Coursera and I have the following doubts in my code. The following is my piece of code.

```
 rankall <- function(outcome, num = "best") {

  ## Read outcome data
  dat <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv")





## Check that outcome are valid
  outcomeValues <- c("heart attack", "heart failure", "pneumonia")

  if(!(outcome %in% outcomeValues)){
    stop("invalid outcome")


    }

  column <- if(outcome == "heart attack"){
    11
  }
  else if(outcome == "heart failure"){
    17
  }
  else if(outcome == "pneumonia") {
    23
  }

  dat[, column] <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(levels(dat[, column])[dat[, column]]))
  dat[, 2] <- as.character(dat[, 2])
  dat[, 11] <- as.numeric(dat[, 11]) # heart attack
  dat[, 17] <- as.numeric(dat[, 17]) # heart failure
  dat[, 23] <- as.numeric(dat[, 23]) # pneumonia
  output <- vector()
  states <- levels(dat[, 7])

  ## Return hospital name in that state with lowest 30-day death rate
  ## For each state, find the hospital of the given rank
  for( i in 1:length(states)){




 stateData <- dat[grep(states[i], dat$State), ]
  outcomeData <- stateData[order(stateData[, column], stateData[, 2], na.last = NA), ]
  hospital <- if(num == "best" || num == 1){
    outcomeData[1, 2]
  }
  else if(num == "worst") {
    outcomeData[nrow(outcomeData), 2]
  }
  else {
    outcomeData[num, 2]
  }
  result <- append(result, c(hospital, states[i]))
  }




## Return a data frame with the hospital names and the (abbreviated) state name
  result <- as.data.frame(matrix(result, nrow = length(states), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))
  colnames(result) <- c("Hospital names", "State")


  result
  }
```

In the above code, if I replace 
`states <- levels(dat[, 7])` by `states <- unique(dat[,7])` , I am not getting the correct outputs. I don't understand why.

And also, if I take down

```
dat[, column] <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(levels(dat[, column])[dat[, column]]))
```

My code doesn't generate the right outputs. I have tried pulling up the suppresswarnings documentation but either I missed the point somewhere or I couldn't find the right answer anywhere.

Comment: could you `dput(head(dat))` please? It would make it easier to follow your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because factor column might have more levels than actual values, e.g.:

```
x <- factor(1:3, levels = 1:4)
x
# [1] 1 2 3
# Levels: 1 2 3 4

unique(x)
# [1] 1 2 3
# Levels: 1 2 3 4
length(unique(x))
# [1] 3

levels(x)
# [1] "1" "2" "3" "4"
length(levels(x))
# [1] 4
```

This is helpful when we later want to add value "4" to x.